# How to Change email notification

Tags: discussion, notifications, email

For some reason, I stopped receiving notifications when someone replied to my question.

I can’t find the settings location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to your user profile https://superuser.com/users/383137/susik
2. Click on <kbd>Settings</kbd>
3. Click on <kbd>Edit email settings</kbd>
4. Scroll down to **Inbox**
5. Choose one of **Off**, **3 hrs**, **Daily** or **Weekly**

Comment: I noticed that it was set to daily. I expected to see Instant but since we don’t have it … I have changed it to 3 hours. Btw: how could I validate that it took effect? Thank you

Comment: You will only get the emails if you don't read them in your inbox/